# Is it possible to run a task on the last day of the month using taskmgr?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-manager

I noticed you can only set the day of the month as a positive number 1..31 in the scheduled task GUI on Windows (Windows server 2003).

Is it possible to run a task only on the *last* day of the month? (This isn't a fixed day number, e.g. in February it could be the 28th or 29th day of the month, and in other months it may be the 30th or 31th.)

Related question, if I set a task to run on the 31th of every month, will it actually run in months with less days? Or will it run on the 1st of the next month in such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the task using the [schtasks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) command with the `/mo LASTDAY` option:

> **schtasks** schedules commands and programs to run
>   periodically or at a specific time.
>   Adds and removes tasks from the
>   schedule, starts and stops tasks on
>   demand, and displays and changes
>   scheduled tasks.

**Syntax:**

```
schtasks /create /tn TaskName /tr TaskRun /sc schedule [/mo modifier]
         [/d day] [/m month[,month...] [/i IdleTime] [/st StartTime] 
         [/sd StartDate] [/ed EndDate] [/s computer [/u 
         [domain\]user /p password]] 
         [/ru {[Domain\]User | "System"} [/rp Password]] /?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the user interface.
When creating a trigger for a task, select `monthly` from the radio list. Then, for `Months` select `<Select all months>` and for `Days` select `Last`.

[image: Selecting All Months]

[image: Selecting Last]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the GUI supports it natively, but you could get the task to kick off a vbs script or something before hand. Something like:

sub LastDateOfCurMonth()
dim lstDateCurMonth, fstDateCurMonth, fstDateNxtMonth
       fstDateCurMonth="01/" & Month(date) & "/" & Year(Date) 
       fstDateNxtMonth=DateAdd("m",1,fstDateCurMonth)
       lstDateCurMonth=DateAdd("d",-1,fstDateNxtMonth)
       wscript.echo "Last Date of Current Month is: " & lstDateCurMonth
End Sub

Comment: The script I need to run exit immediately if tomorrow it is the same month as today, so this workaround would be trivial. (I've actually set it up now to just run the script every day; on anything but last day of month it's a no-op.)

Answer (score 1):

Set up multiple schedules for the same task.  One schedule for months that end on the 31st, one for months that end on the 30th, and another for the 28th.  All you have to do is give each task a unique name.

Comment: Or, create a single task with multiple triggers.